# How can we use Scipy Optimize to Maximize Revenue Columns in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy-optimize

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Stadium':3000, 'Casino':3000, 'Airport':3000, 'Max':20000}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Stadium':3000, 'Casino':5000, 'Airport':5000, 'Max':10000},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Stadium':7000, 'Casino':5000, 'Airport':7000, 'Max':12000}, 
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Stadium':3000, 'Casino':6000, 'Airport':2000, 'Max':10000}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


cols = ['Stadium', 'Casino', 'Airport']
df['Aggregations'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
df
```

[image]

I am trying to maximize the 'Aggregation' column subject to the constraints in the 'Max' column, so I can't exceed the limit in the Max column.

The columns named Stadium, Casino, and Airport show revenue data. I want to maximize the revenue, per date, without exceeding the Max value. Lower bound is 0 and upper bound is .5.

```
So, in row=0, Stadium, Casino, and Airport would be .333 each.
In row=1, Casino and Airport would be .5 each, and Stadium would be 0.
In row=2, Stadium and Airport would be .5 each, and Casino would be 0.
In row=3, Stadium would be .333, Casino would be .5, and Airport would be .1.
```

I am playing with this code, but it's giving me .5 for everything!

```
# Define the objective function to maximize
def objective_function(variables):
    return -np.sum(variables)

# Define the constraint function to enforce the 'Max' constraint
def max_constraint(variables):
    return df['Max'].values - np.sum(variables)

# Initial guess for optimization
initial_guess = np.zeros(len(cols))

# Constraints
constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': max_constraint}]

# Bounds for each column
bounds = [(0, .5)]

# Perform the optimization
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_guess, bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

# Retrieve the optimized values for the columns
optimized_values = result.x

# Update the DataFrame with the optimized values
df[cols] = optimized_values

# Recalculate the 'Aggregations' column
df['Aggregations'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)

# Display the updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: You're never actually using `df` in your objective function. You're just telling scipy that the objective is the sum of how many of each column and the constraint is that sum must be less than the aggregate column. Since 0.5*3 (for 3 columns) is always less than aggregate, that's what scipy returns.

Comment: Why are the results as you say? For the first row, 1/3 of each of the columns sums to 3000 when the max is 20000, so you could have taken 1/2 of each column to get 4500. So what is the operation you're actually trying to maximize?

Comment: I am trying to maximize the values in Stadium, Casino, and Airport per date, so if the Max<Aggregations, this is the Max. Or, if Aggregations<Max, this is the Max. In row=0, Stadium=3000+Casino=3000+Airport=3000 is 9000. In row=3, Stadium=2000+Casino=6000+Airport=1000 is 10000. The Max is 10000, so I need to truncate Airport because the revenue is less in this row, so I'll invest less money in this asset.

Comment: But why is 0.5 for all wrong for the first row?

Comment: I don't think that would work, because in row=0, I have revenue of 3000, 3000, and 3000. These are all equal, so the optimizer should allocate .33, .33, and .33. In row=1, I have revenues 3000, 5000, and 5000. The max is 10000, so the optimizer should allocate 0, .5, and .5. That's may take on it. Maybe there is another way to maximize the allocations of revenue. I want to find the maximum allocations per date, for Stadium, Casino, and Airport.

Comment: But you haven't explained _why_ the optimizer should choose those values. They sum to less than aggregate as is, so why not take the maximum you can? As is, your problem sounds underconstrained.

Comment: This makes no sense. In your row 3 reference example, the dot product of your desired output fractions and the incremental revenues is equal to your `Aggregations`, which (1) you haven't included in your dataframe, only in an image; and (2) exceeds the maximum.